# Picking values from column according values from combination of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have problem with my data filtering in pandas. I have data with 3 columns - CHROM|POS|FST. I am trying to filter out data according CHROM|POS from main datafram CHROM|POS values.

```py
# Fst data - same CHROM|POS as main_exones dataframe

# exones


Fst_exones_update = Fst_exones.loc[Fst_exones["CHROM"].isin(main_exones["CHROM"]) & Fst_exones["POS"].isin(main_exones["POS"]), :].reset_index(drop=True)

# genes

Fst_genes_update = Fst_genes.loc[Fst_genes["CHROM"].isin(main_genes["CHROM"]) & Fst_genes["POS"].isin(main_genes["POS"]), :].reset_index(drop=True)
 
# Setting Fst column - pick all data with same CHROM & POS value in stats dataframes.

# exones

stats_exones["FST"] = Fst_exones_update.loc[(Fst_exones_update["CHROM"].isin(stats_exones["CHROM"])) & (Fst_exones_update["POS"].isin(stats_exones["POS"])), "WEIR_AND_COCKERHAM_FST"].fillna("NaN")


# genes

stats_genes["FST"] = Fst_genes_update.loc[(Fst_genes_update["CHROM"].isin(stats_genes["CHROM"]))&(Fst_genes_update["POS"].isin(stats_genes["POS"])), "WEIR_AND_COCKERHAM_FST"].fillna("NaN")


# Exporting filtered data

# exones

Fst_exones_update.to_excel("FstExon_CSCN_filtrpd.xlsx")

# # genes

Fst_genes_update.to_excel("FstGenes_CSCN_filtrpd.xlsx")
```

I tried to check it with subset smaller subset of that data. Main idea was, that if i pick the values of subset in whole data according same procedure (filtered with CHROM|POS combination; AND() + COUNTIF() function in excel), it should have same value of Fst column as in whole data.

However I noticed that my output file have totaly different values of that subset, if I am trying to check it. So I am despread, because I cannot find any problem with the procedure at all.

data sample:

```py
# main sample

main_exones = pd.DataFrame({
    "CHROM": ["chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1"],
    "POS": [1020264,1020355,1041218,1041220,1043382,1043594,1043663,1044017,1044368,1046562]
})

# fst input sample

fst_exones_sample = pd.DataFrame({
    "CHROM":["chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1"],
    "POS":[1020217,1020236,1020264,1020355,1020363,1022260,1034275,1034290,1034393,1040649],
    "WEIR_AND_COCKERHAM_FST": [0.00844,0.034622,0.011463,0.034622,-0.005786,0.005786,0.046115,-0.005878,0.005786,0.011463],
    }
)

# output sample

stats_exones_output_sample = pd.DataFrame({
    "CHROM":["chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1"],
    "POS": [1020264,1020355,1041218,1041220,1043382,1043594,1043663,1044017,1044368,1046562],
    "Fst": [0.011463,0.034622,-0.005878,-0.005878,-0.009035,-0.0101136,0.011463,0.034622,-0.002662,-0.011854]

})
```

Tried filtered it out with pandas .isin method, & operator and .loc function.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your dataset and the matching expected output

Comment: @mozway I am not sure, if it wont be messy and it is too much to actually pick data, where is the effect present. Still I ll try

Comment: Please read [how to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464)

Comment: @mozway I get it, but my data is from .xlsx files only.

Comment: Well, you **can** craft a minimal example as text, or better as a pandas DataFrame. This requires some work from your side, but this will make your question understandable and easier to reproduce.

Comment: @mozway Thank you for pointing that out. It is my first time to actually posting about pandas, and I am glad that you point out the usable dataframe. Don't worry, I am here for different opinion, not only answer on this subject.

Comment: I don't understand the output, how do you get `-0.005878` in the third row?

Comment: @mozway If you have very low data input, when you compete Fst score, the output can be negativem, eventhough it is score from 0 to 1. I found out, that you can replace it as 0 because of that, but haven't changed it, because of autenticity of dataframe.

Comment: Then, I don't understand the logic. Please clarify how the numbers should be mapped

Comment: @mozway The Fst data comes from vcftools tool, when you put .vcf file with two samples .txt files, which then generate Fst stastistic for whole vcf file. Because I have in this case over 78000 rows, i needed to filtered it according some stable columns in dataframes. The main dataframe have values from filtering out empty values and according some score (Cadd_pred). So I decided to filtered the Fst statistics with the combination of CHROM and POS value match, because it cant have duplicate values of CHROM|POS. Hope I answer the right question.

Comment: No, this gives context but doesn't explain **how** you expect to "filter". For each row in the output, can you describe how you decide on a match? How would you do it manually?

Comment: @mozwayOh, I get it. I would find same CHROM value and POS value as in output file. After that pick the value from main Fst file. If there would not be match, i write down NaN as value. Thank you for this idea. It is cleaver to try to find out way, how to actually do it manualy.

Comment: I get it now. I use main data to do output so I technically am doing the filtering with .isin two times, because i am not changing the main data but only adding new columns to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was technicaly problem with matching two columns from two different sized dataframes pairwise and unproper usage .isin() method.

my solution:

- creating new columns with combined CHROM and POS value
- merging two dataframes to match same values with combined column
- pick only necessary values - CHROM|POS|FST|combined1|combined2
- filter out all NaN values
- use dict(zip()) combiantion - get values of combined column with fst values together
- map dict on input dataframe creating new Fst column

```py
#  Creating Fst column for Fst scores data

#  Combining CHROM|POS - Combined columns

##  Exones

Fst_exones["Combined_Fst"] = Fst_exones["CHROM"].astype(str) + "_" + Fst_exones["POS"].astype(str)
main_exones["Combined_main_exones"] = main_exones["CHROM"].astype(str) + "_" + main_exones["POS"].astype(str)

##  Genes

Fst_genes["Combined_Fst"] = Fst_genes["CHROM"].astype(str) + "_" + Fst_genes["POS"].astype(str)
main_genes["Combined_main_genes"] = main_genes["CHROM"].astype(str) + "_" + main_genes["POS"].astype(str)

#  Merging dataframes → setting similar combined data

##  Exones

merged_exones = Fst_exones.merge(main_exones, left_on='Combined_Fst', right_on='Combined_main_exones', how='left')

##  Genes

merged_genes = Fst_genes.merge(main_genes,left_on='Combined_Fst', right_on='Combined_main_genes', how='left')


#  Filtering only usefull columns from merged dataframes

##  Exones

merged_exones_position = merged_exones.loc[:,["CHROM_x", "POS_x", "WEIR_AND_COCKERHAM_FST", "Combined_Fst", "CHROM_y", "POS_y", "Combined_main_exones"]].reset_index(drop=True)

##  Genes

merged_genes_position = merged_genes.loc[:,["CHROM_x", "POS_x", "WEIR_AND_COCKERHAM_FST", "Combined_Fst", "CHROM_y", "POS_y", "Combined_main_genes"]].reset_index(drop=True)


#  Setting Fst columns

##  Exones

merged_exones_filtered = merged_exones_position[merged_exones_position["Combined_main_exones"].notna()].reset_index(drop=True)

merged_exones_filtered_dict = dict(zip(merged_exones_filtered["Combined_main_exones"],merged_exones_filtered["WEIR_AND_COCKERHAM_FST"]))

main_exones["Fst"] = main_exones["Combined_main_exones"].map(merged_exones_filtered_dict)

##  Genes

merged_genes_filtered = merged_genes_position[merged_genes_position["Combined_main_genes"].notna()].reset_index(drop=True)

merged_genes_filtered_dict = dict(zip(merged_genes_filtered["Combined_main_genes"],merged_genes_filtered["WEIR_AND_COCKERHAM_FST"]))

main_genes["Fst"] = main_genes["Combined_main_genes"].map(merged_genes_filtered_dict)
```